# Word Square - AXLE

Tags: wordplay, word-square

Fill in ~ with letters to create a real words vertically, horizontally, and diagonally. Vertical and horizontal words have to be the same:

~ A ~ ~

A X L E

~ L ~ ~

~ E ~ ~

Edit: Final

Comment: What counts as a "real word", exactly?

Comment: Wait, which one do you want us to answer? Do both diagonals have to be real words?

Comment: I actually don't know but its one of them.

Comment: Did you find this puzzle somewhere else? (And you didn't answer the other questions - do both of the diagonals have to be real words? *What counts as a 'real word'?*)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, depending on what counts as a valid word. Here's one:

> [image]

Comment: YLLY isn't a word?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I assumed only the main diagonal (\\) needed to be a word? There are no English words of the form \_LL\_, where both blanks are the same.

Comment: Another one (using less common words) is EACH, AXLE, CLEW, HEWS